# How to display FBX data(using microsoft 3DViewer) same as Blender displays

Tags: export, import

**Introduction**

Thank you for reading in advance.
and I am sorry for my bad English.

My problem is that an FBX file looks different when displayed with MS 3D Viewer and Blender.

How to make it look the same in both?

**One Data, Different Results**
[image: Mesh at left are FBX data imported, and right side are .blend data]
Mesh at left are FBX data imported, and right side are .blend data

[image: How to display with]
When 3DViewer shows FBX data

[image]
How to make FBX Data

**The files are here**

FBX file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7d5vnspwfqqnsc/test002.fbx?dl=0

.blend file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwqzbwva82awnuf/howto_display_same.blend?dl=0

**My status**

Beginner with only half year experiment on hobby use.

I can use basic skill of Blender but Animation, Physics

I have searched several hours about similar question, but no answer found.